# Getting the value from option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello im doing some try and error. This is the code where select-option populate from database but this gives me null value

```
echo "<option  value=\"\">"."Select"."</option>";
$qry = "select * from try where name = '".$_POST['name']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['trynum']."'>".$row['tryname']."</option>";
}
```

---

```
     $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "json_php_sub.php",
             data: {instructor:$(this).val()},
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(result){
            alert(result);
                document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML = result;
            }
        });
```

---

```
<select id="sub" name="subb"></select>
```

my problem is whether i select from dropdown the content is there but no value. pls help..

Comment: You have `dataType:'json'` but you're returning html.

Comment: Protip: `this.value` > `$(this).val()`

Comment: You would have seen what @JasonP said if you had the console window open on the browser while watching the AJAX request / response.

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection, by the way.

Comment: fast reply.. what dataType should i use? any link where can i read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PHP:

```
 $ajaxAnswer = "<option  value=\"\">"."Select"."</option>";
 $instructor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['instructor']);
 $qry = "select * from try where name = '".$instructor."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $ajaxAnswer .= "<option value='".$row['trynum']."'>".$row['tryname']."</option>";
 }
 echo $ajaxAnswer;
```

#### Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "json_php_sub.php",
        data: {instructor:$(this).val()},
        success: function(result){
            $("#sub").html(result);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {instructor:$('#SELECT_ELEMTN_ID').val()},
```

Depending on scope and stuff, you may not wanna use "this".

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "phpfile.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {                            
                        $('#selectdata').append('<option value="'+obj.user_id+'">'+obj.user_name+'</option>' )

                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selectdata">

    </select>
</body>
```

**phpfile.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="";
$database= "databasename";

$con = mysqli_connect($host , $user , $password);
$database_connect = mysqli_select_db($con, $database);

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select Id as user_id,Name as user_name from users");
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```